# Significance of the numbers next to the people in Anne's drawing

Tags: analysis, the-others

In the movie, *The Others*, what is the significance of the numbers next to the people in Anne's drawing? The boy, Victor, had a **5** next to him and the "witch" had a **14**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is explained at the same time as the numbers are shown. It's the number of times that she has seen the drawn person.

See 2 mins in at:

"what do these numbers stand for?"

"that's the number of times I've seen them"